# Learn Numerical methods in Python

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation, numerical-optimization

Please suggest me some texts that I could use to learn Numerical Methods in Python (irrespective of 2.7 or 3.x). I would like to improve my coding skills with Python along with refreshing my math in Numerical Methods.

The one book I am referring to right now is: [Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python 3 by [Jaan Kiusalaas]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107033853)

Comment: Your question is too broad. It will be closed if you don't make more precise what exactly you are interested in (linear algebra, ordinary differential equation, partial differential equations, integral equations, transcendental equations, ...)

Comment: @ProfessorVector: interested in Linear algebra and optimization. Added to the question.

Comment: https://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/half/book.pdf

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel : That book is a primer on Python Programming Language and not on Numerical methods in Python.

Answer (score -1):

A standard book deriving from a basic course at University of Oslo is

Hans Petter Langtangen
[A Primer on Scientific Programming with Python](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662498866).

Then, if you are searching from the point-of-view of an engineering student you might like to use

Svein Linge, Hans Petter Langtangen
[Programming for Computations - Python](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319812823#otherversion=9783319324289).

Another, very compact, book is

Joakim Sundnes
[Introduction to Scientific Programming with Python](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030503550).